# How to get it onclick value or onchange value

Tags: jquery

Do not know how to use jquery or javascript to get onchange () value and onclick () value
I want to get onchange (VALUE) and onclick (VALUE)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category" value="3" onchange="box_val('3','3')">
```

Get  3 , 3

or

```
<input type="text" name="category[]" id="category" value="3" onclick ="box_val('3','3')">
```

Get  3 , 3

or

Modify get onchange (VALUE) and onclick (VALUE)
box_val('3','3')  to   box_val('4','4')

Comment: What output do you want? Do you get any error? Do you have any JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#category").change(function(){ 
    $('#category').val('3');
});


$('#category').click (function () {
   $('#category').val('3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="category[]" id="category" value="1">
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create event handler and use type to check which is being done.

Although it bothers me why you need two events

```js
$('#category').on('click change', function(e) {


  if (e.type == 'click') {
    console.log('click')
  }
  if (e.type == 'change') {
    console.log('change')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category" value="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function box_val(Text){
  alert(Text);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category" value="3" onchange="box_val($(this).val());">
<input type="text" name="category[]" id="category" value="3" onclick ="box_val($(this).val());">
```

Answer (score 0):

you the below script

```
<script>
    function myFunction(x,y) {
        alert(x,y);
    }
</script>
```